# How to create a hyperlink in word to open the containing folder of a target file

Tags: ms-word

Purpose is to create links from article in a word document to open a folder that contains some related files.

MS.Word Hyperlinks on OSX can open the parent folder that contains this Applescript

```
tell application "Finder"
  open POSIX path of ((container of (path to me))
end tell
```

How do I create such a functionality in MS.Word on Windows? So clicking a word hyperlink opens a folder that is the containing folder of a file that the link points to?

Creating a shortcut to the parent folder and pointing it from MS.Word does not work if the parent folder location is changed. Is there a way to create a shortcut in Windows with a relative path without using 3rd party programs?

Comment: Got it with more Googles. Batch Files on Windows.